# How to use .svg graphics in a Kivy TextInput?

Tags: python, python-3.x, svg, kivy

I've recently found a set of emojis that I would like to be able to use in text. They are in .svg format and I have no idea how to insert them. I have a `TextInput` to input the message and a custom widget that uses a `TextInput` to display the text afterwards. I'd gladly appreciate any help, links, articles, anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit2:**

As @RyanP explained in the comments, I presume a font holds images of emojis and therefore the only thing you'd need to do is take your font(or directly one of fonts kivy uses) and add/replace images of emoji in that font with your `.svg`s for each emoji.

This [table](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html) will surely help you and also [fontforge](http://fontforge.github.io). [Here](https://fontforge.github.io/importexample.html) is a part of the docs about importing svgs.

In case that it'd be not possible to do such a thing, I'll still leave the rest of my answer below.

---

I don't know if `TextInput` is capable of doing such thing - inserting .svg or well any picture into itself, because it renders text.

However I can see a workaround as making for each emoji some text equivalent or tag - `[smileemoji]` for example. Then after you submit your text, make a function that will replace tags with emojis. However, it won't go with Label in the way as it's written because it also renders text alone.

**How I see it:**

- you can use label that will be a size of its text, then place emoji and then another label with remaining text. But you'll have issues with wrapping it, because you won't be able to break a line like in the second example(at least I don't know how) so that it'd remain a single widget.

  - 1: `bla bla bla` emoji `remaining text`
  - 2: bla bla bla bla bla bla bla `remaining`
        `text`
- as a second option I'd recommend you making a single label, then:

  - emoji has to have constant size
  - make for each tag a special character(s) in your text that will be constant size(use markup) - I recommend you something that'll highly resemble *square shape*
  - place an `Image` with same width as your special character(s) on the top of the `Label`, so that it'll behave as an image in your text, but in reality it'll be another widget

The second option seems logical to me, because `Label` will handle the wrapping and the only thing you need to find and set is the constant size and *location* of that character in your text *on the screen*(so that you could position the `Image` widget - not position in string).

If you want to remain with `TextInput` as output manager, no problem, but you'll have to manage the sizing of your special character yourself inside the `TextInput` and - maybe the ugliest part - handle the color of `Image` widget if your output manager changes color like for example `TextInput` does on focus/defocus so that it wouldn't look weird.

Also there's scrolling, you'd need to handle that too, so that your emojis don't float around without a reason or stay on the top of your `Label`/`TextInput` while the text changes.

All in case, that your emoji will be transparent or that its background color will be consistent with your output manager color.

**Edit:**

If you want only some emoticons, drop the image idea and go for tags and replacing with unicode [1](http://unicodeemoticons.com/), [2](https://gist.github.com/endolith/157796).

Comment: The appropriate placeholders are the Unicode emoji.

Comment: @RyanP Yeah I know that emojis use placeholders in unicode, but it'll not help him rendering it into TextInput :-/ He'll probably see only blank space, or not?

Comment: Not placeholders, actual Unicode emoji.  They will render in Kivy if the font supports those characters. The key would be to replace those characters with the images during the label rendering process.

Comment: Oh, that's pretty good. In that case I presume a font holds images for emoji, therefore he'd just need to make a custom font, which is easy and there is a lot of free tools.